# Flutter calling navigator inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a login screen, but I don't want the user to see the login screen if they're already logged in, so I'm saving their login information using shared preference.

The login screen is the default route, with the following pseduo-code

```dart
return Column(
  children: [
    CustomLogo(),
    FutureBuilder(
      future: isUserLoggedIn() // can take some time,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          bool isUserSignedIn = snapshot.data ?? false;
          if (isUserSignedIn) {
            // Here's the part of interest of this question
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, dashboardRouteName);
          }
          return AuthCard();
        }
      else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("An error occured");
      }
      else {
        return CircularProgressInidicator();
      }
    ), // end of FutureBuilder
  ] // end of widget
) // end of Column
```

The produced error is

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#d56ee]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  FutureBuilder<bool>)
```

I understood the error a bit, but how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I would suggest you to instead calling the future in a future builder, you should run that function in main function before calling runApp();

For Ex:

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn") ?? false;
    runApp(MyApp(isUserLoggedIn: isLoggedIn));
}
```

and MyApp class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final bool isUserLoggedIn;
  
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.isUserLoggedIn}): super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => isUserLoggedIn ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
        //Other routes,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This will prevent user's seeing login page for a split second and also while fetching the shared_preferences the app will show Splash Screen, so it won't cause a problem.